# How to Create asteroids on the x and y axes

Tags: c, malloc, abstract-data-type

I'm doing `Asteroids` (Atari) in `C`. I designed the `ADT` for asteroids, all the `ADT` is related to 1 asteroid.

I need to create an asteroid in a random position, but random within `(0, y)` or `(x, 0)`

I have my function `asteroid_create()`:

```
asteroid_t *asteroid_create(float x, float y, float radio){
    asteroid_t *ast = malloc(sizeof(asteroid_t));

    ast->x_pos = x;
    ast->y_pos = y;

    ast->radio = radio;

    ast->vx = rand_float((1000/ast->radio)-100,(1000/ast->radio)+100);
    ast->vy = rand_float((1000/ast->radio)-100,(1000/ast->radio)+100);

    ast->angle = rand_float(0,2*PI);

    size_t rock_rand = rand() % ASTEROIDS_TYPES;
    ast->name_rock = rocks_dictionary[rock_rand];

    return ast;
}
```

That creates an asteroid with certain fixed variables. Then, in another file, I create a list of asteroids and I'm inserting as many asteroids I need.

```
bool asteroids_insert(list_t* l){
    asteroid_t *ast = asteroid_create(rand_float(0,WINDOW_WIDTH),rand_float(0,WINDOW_HIGH),AST_INITIAL_RADIO);
    if(!list_append(l,ast))
        return false;
    return true;

}
```

In the main:

```
for(size_t i=0; i< ASTEROIDS_INITIAL;i++){
        asteroids_insert(list_asteroids);
    }
```

In this way, I am creating asteroids anywhere on the screen. I only need them to be generated on the y axis or the x axis.

The way I am doing it, I can't think of how I can do what I need. How can I do it so that asteroid_create() receive as a parameter positions in `(0, y)` or `(x, 0)` randomly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you bend the `y` axis down to the left, so that in effect it becomes the "negative part" of the `x` axis.

Generate a random number `value` between `-MAX_Y` and `+MAX_X`.

If the resulting number is `0` your point is `(0, 0)`; if it's positive, your point is `(value, 0)`, otherwise it's `(0, -value)`.

*Note: if your `x` axis is larger than `y` axis, this will make it more probable to generate points on the `x` axis.*

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I needed exactly that